# Creating additional column in SQL that keep count of values corresponding to particular columns

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL Table:

```
id  p_action0   p_action1   p_action2
1   p_A_id1      p_B_id3    p_A_id2
2   p_A_id1      p_C_id3    p_B_id1
3   p_A_id1      p_A_id1    p_A_id1
4   p_B_id1      p_B_id1    p_C_id3
5   p_B_id1      p_B_id1    p_A_id1
```

There are 3 types of action : p_A, p_B, p_C.
Now, I need to update the table with 3 additional columns that gives a count for each id of each type.What would be the Oracle SQl query for that? The final table should be like this.

```
id  p_action0   p_action1   p_action2   TypeA   TypeB   TypeC
1   p_A_id1     p_B_id3     p_A_id2        2       1     0
2   p_A_id1     p_C_id3     p_B_id1        1       1     1
3   p_A_id1     p_A_id1     p_A_id1        3       0     0
4   p_B_id1     p_B_id1     p_C_id3        0       2     1
5   p_B_id1     p_B_id1     p_A_id1        1       2     0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MY_SQL_TABLE
   SET TypeA =
            (CASE WHEN p_action0 LIKE 'p_A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action1 LIKE 'p_A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action2 LIKE 'p_A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       TypeB =
            (CASE WHEN p_action0 LIKE 'p_B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action1 LIKE 'p_B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action2 LIKE 'p_B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       TypeC =
            (CASE WHEN p_action0 LIKE 'p_C%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action1 LIKE 'p_C%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action2 LIKE 'p_C%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

As a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_SQL_VIEW
AS
   SELECT id,
          p_action0,
          p_action1,
          p_action2,
            (CASE WHEN p_action0 LIKE 'p_A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action1 LIKE 'p_A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action2 LIKE 'p_A%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             typeA,
            (CASE WHEN p_action0 LIKE 'p_B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action1 LIKE 'p_B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action2 LIKE 'p_B%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             typeB,
            (CASE WHEN p_action0 LIKE 'p_C%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action1 LIKE 'p_C%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          + (CASE WHEN p_action2 LIKE 'p_C%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             typeC
     FROM my_sql_table;
```

... and then:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_SQL_VIEW;
```

Comment: just a comment I would leave your original table alone and implement a solution like UltraCommits as a view.  then display the info from the view,  otherwise trying to keep that table in sync with CRUD operations is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: ... just edited adding the solution with an Oracle view!